# Taking Data from XML URL using scanner, NoSuchElementException

Tags: xml, java.util.scanner

I am trying to take data from Yahoo's stock API and print it out for my class. Right now, I create a URL that is

```
String stockURL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22" + ticker + "%22)&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
```

where ticker is a user inputted string (e.g. AAPL, GOOGL, YHOO, etc).

I pass the URL into my scanners like this:

```
Scanner webReader = null;
Scanner bufferReader = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL(stockURL);
    webReader = new Scanner(url.openStream());
    bufferReader = new Scanner(url.openStream());
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And save the information like this

```
    String name = "";
    String highLow = "";
    boolean yes = true;
    while(bufferReader.nextLine()!=null){
        String holder = webReader.nextLine();
        if(holder.startsWith("<Name>")){
            name = holder.replaceAll("<Name>", "");
            name.replaceAll("</Name>", "");
        } else if(holder.startsWith("<YearRange>")){
            highLow = holder.replaceAll("YearRange","");
            highLow.replaceAll("</YearRange>","");
            highLow.replaceAll("- ", "and a year high of:");
            break;
        } else if(holder.startsWith("</Query>")){
            yes = false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Yet I get a NoSuchElementException at my while(bufferReader.nextLine!=null)).

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!

Simply replace the condition in the while loop.

```
while(webReader.hasNext()){...}
```